# Extract .zip to %appdata%\subfolder

Tags: c#, zip, appdata

I want to extract a zip to `%appdata%\subfolder`. When I put a route such as `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\subfolder`, it extracts ok; I want to do this for each `%appdata%` of the client systems.

I’m using SharpZipLib to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `%appdata%` in your code using `SpecialFolder` enum -

```
string appdata = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                       System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Comment: Thanks, now if I want to extract in %appdata%\folder how i do this?

Comment: `string folderPath = appdata + @"\folder";`